# shrink top banners on mobile display

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been trying different height width combinations since long and also searched on the internet and on this site for some resource. Either I found some people with similar questions with no solution or there are solutions that does not resolve my problem. Please help.

I am using a wide screen DELL monitor. My web page is based on 100% width. On the top, I have my logo on the left and on its right, i have added 5 banners of sizes 120x60, 234x60, 234x60, 468x60, 468x60. Under the logo and banners, I have a big table.

On my monitor everything looks fine. What can I do so that all the 5 banners resize automatically when viewed on my laptop, monitor of square/different size, tablet and mobile. The table shrinks on mobile display automatically but not the banners. Please help.

sample code here: Logo and all banners are visible on my desktop (resolution 1920x1080) but when viewed on other desktop/laptop/table/mobile it does not resize

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sample</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://www.microstrategy.com/Strategy/media/images/common/customer-logos/logo_ebay.jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.crossingstv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/120x60.png"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The above table approach worked fine. Trying to work with div approach but it isnt working

```
<style>
#tophead{
    width: 100%;
}
#mainhead{
    width: 15%;
}
#adhead{
    width: 85%;
    position: absolute;
    right:0px;
    top: 15px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;    
}
</style>

<div id="tophead">

  <div id="mainhead">
    <img src="http://www.microstrategy.com/Strategy/media/images/common/customer-logos/logo_ebay.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="adhead">
    <img src="http://www.crossingstv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/120x60.png">
    <img src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif">
    <img src="http://www.bingobugle.com/images/ex234x60.gif">
    <img src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.chilefoundry.com/wp-content/uploads/468x60banner.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can do this using javascipt, in javascript there is Navigator Object. using this object you will know about the user agent. from that you can guess its a mobile phone. another way there is also window.screen object, windows.screen,width will give you width of the screen, window.screen.height will give you height of screen, reading this value you can change the banner size on different platforms.

Comment: thanks for your reply. javascript is not my language and cannot understand what exactly to do with this. However, I understood that you are telling me to get the user size and then program it accordingly. Cant this be guessed? if it is a mobile display, the resolution would be somewhere around 720p and tablet/laptop/desktop/wide desktop would be bigger. Is there an easy way to do this? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the images adapt to their parent's size using:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;    
}
```

They will be very small than, so you might want to switch from table-layout to block-layout and give each it's own line

```
table, tr, td {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: code updated in my original post. i cannot send a link to the page as it is on my local computer and not hosted yet. thanks

Comment: ok, as you are already using a table, `max-width: 100%; and height: auto;` for the images should be enough to make them responsive

Comment: <table width="100%" border="0" style="max-width: 100px; height: auto;"> Is this what you meant? I tried it but it doesnt work, it puts a horizontal scrollbar...

Comment: Thanks David.. Iam trying to learn more on this and therefore I removed the table and tried with the div tag approach but it did not work. any ideas??? question updated with new code. Thanks